# DeviceIoControl buffer parameters marshalling and alignment

Tags: c++, service, windows-ce, memory-alignment

I am writing a Windows CE service and an API library for it, which wraps [DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms898288.aspx) calls needed to communicate with the library.
Can I be sure, that marshalling of memory buffers passed to the DeviceIoControl function will not break any memory aligned data? E.g., if I call the DeviceIoControl the following way:

```
int32_t value = 5; // properly aligned at 4 bytes
DeviceIoControl(handle, IOCTL_CODE, &value, sizeof(value), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

can I handle it on the service side the following way:

```
    BOOL APIENTRY SRV_IOControl(DWORD data, DWORD code, PBYTE inputBuffer, DWORD inputBufferLength, /*other params*/)
    {
       if ((code == IOCTL_CODE) && (inputBufferLength == sizeof(int32_t)))
       {
          // if inputBuffer is not aligned to 4 bytes, then this may produce  
          // unaligned memory access failure on some ARM processors
          int32_t value = *(reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(inputBuffer)); 
       }
       //...
    }
```

In Windows CE 6.0 each process uses it's own address space, so the memory buffer passed from a client to a service needs to be marshalled by the OS somehow, e.g. through memory aliasing or copying. The (potential) problem can be prematurely solved on the service side by using the UNALIGNED (__unaligned) Visual C++ extension keyword, or by copying buffers to an aligned destination. But since all these need more work from developer  and from CPU, it's good to avoid it if it's known that the problem does not exist at all.

Comment: This is not a real problem.

Comment: @HansPassant, and by this do you mean that the problem does not really exist? I.e. the DeviceIoControl will not affect alignment of a passed buffer and I can safely dereference it's content (provided it's properly aligned on the caller side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DeviceIoControl` call will not change the alignment of any data that it marshals, so whatever alignment you have at the source is what you'll get in the driver.  That's not to say that you could screw things up using `UNALIGNED` in a caller and the driver then would break, but if the caller is doing that, it's on them, and your driver shouldn't be expecting unaligned data anyway.